# Extension of A by B given a short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

The following is taken from: *Module Theory An approach to linear algebra Electronic edition* by T.S.Blyth

*Backgroun:*

**Exercise 3.11**

A short exact sequence of the form
$$(f,E,g)\equiv 0\to A\xrightarrow{f}E\xrightarrow{g}B\to 0$$
is called an *extension* of $A$ by $B$.
Given any $R$-modules
$A$ and $B$, show that there exists at least one extension of $A$ by $B$.

*Questions:*

Is the author asking the reader to show what the module $E$ is supposed to be in order to make the above sequence of mappings into a short exact sequence?  If so, it seems that the module $E$ would have to be $E=A\times B$ where the mapping $f:A\to A\times B$ is defined as $a\mapsto (a,0)$ and $g:A\times B\to B$ is defined as $(a,b)\mapsto b.$

Is my understanding of the question correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have to show that $0\to A\xrightarrow{f}E=A\times B\xrightarrow{g}B\to 0$ an exact sequence as well as the maps $f, g$ are both homomorphic?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for your answers.  Can I also trouble you quickly with this follow up [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839340/difference-between-the-concepts-of-extension-a-by-b-and-essential-extension-for).  I just want to know if there are any theorems I should be aware of if any that relates definition 3  and definition 1.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment (especially clear after reading "... thank you for your answers"). Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the direct sum $E=A\oplus B$ is always an $R$-module extension of $A$ by $B$, with the maps $f$ and $g$ you have given. To complete the proof you need to show that the resulting sequence is exact at each point and that all maps are $R$-module homomorphisms. This is not difficult. In fact it is more or less obvious.